# Prior or subsequent art for Microsoft COM’s “causality IDs”

Tags: reference-request, distributed-systems, concurrency, object-oriented

Microsoft COM, in its object RPC part, had a peculiar mechanism that could be used to prohibit concurrent calls to the same object (or another object serviced by the same event loop) but permit callbacks.

When a COM call first crosses an process boundary, it is assigned a unique identifier called a *causality ID* or a *logical thread ID*, which the calling thread remembers; when a further call is made by the called process, it is assigned the same ID; and so forth, until the initial boundary-crossing call finishes. Later releases of DCOM/COM+ would allow you to look at that ID by invoking [`GetCurrentLogicalThreadId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-icomthreadinginfo-getcurrentlogicalthreadid), but from the very beginning [you could use](https://archive.org/details/insideole00broc/page/305/mode/1up?q=CALLTYPE) it to restrict reentrancy, by checking whether your implementation of `IMessageFilter::HandleInComingCall()` received `CALLTYPE_NESTED` or `CALLTYPE_TOPLEVEL_CALLPENDING` in the `dwCallType` argument. In Windows 8, what looks like the same or very similar functionality was repackaged as [application single-treaded apartments (ASTAs)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210224-00/?p=104901).

This is a novel if imperfect mechanism, but surprisingly, I cannot find *any* mentions of it in the literature outside of the context of COM/DCOM/COM+ (and even there not often). None of the inspirations of Microsoft’s RPC design (Apollo, Sun RPC, DCE) used it, as far as I can tell, even though it’s not really tied to objects as such. And neither, it seems, did anybody else afterwards.

Was this technique ever analyzed or even described in any formal way? Did other systems use it?

Comment: Sounds similar to the concept of "Transaction Identifier" in distributed databases. Not only do they allow objects to "see" reentrancy (and prevent it if needed), but they also allow to establish a *logical ordering* of transactions (decide which should happen first), which has an additional benefit of preventing deadlocks.